# Calling setInterval() from setTimeout() does not start timer

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a task to bring up a bootstrap modal window after a predefined time, for which I use setTimeout(). Then another task is to show a countdown in the body of the modal window - however calling setInterval() from setTimeout() function does not do anything.

```
func = function(warntime) {
   func.tid = setInterval(function() {
     $("#dialog-countdown").html(warntime--);
       if(warntime == 0) {
           doSignout();
       }
   }, 1000);
};

var tmwarn = setTimeout(function(){
         $("#timeout-modal").modal("show");
         func(60);
   }, 20000);
```

So the func() call does not start the timer, at least not in Chrome or Safari or IE.

What's wrong? Any workaround?

Comment: Are you actually invoking the functions anywhere?

Comment: Have you ascertained the interval is being started? That warntime is what you expect? Etc. Nothing jumps out at me.

Comment: not enough info here, strip it down the minimum code with necessary values provided to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like that:

```
func = function(warntime) {
   func.tid = setInterval(function() {
     warntime--;
     console.log('warntime: ', warntime);
       if(warntime == 0) {
           doSignout(func.tid);
       }
   }, 2000);
};

doSignout = function(id) {
   console.log('signing out');
   clearInterval(id) 
}

setTimeout(function(){
    func((sessionTimeout - sessionTimeoutWarning)/1000);
}, sessionTimeoutWarning);
```

[here's the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foj57cox/)

Comment: Thanks! Works for me. Still no idea why my own code didn't work, it looks almost same. Any hint on how would I go about restarting that "warntime" counter on user input?

Comment: Your code does not work because you’not calling clearInterval() with interval Id.

Comment: About resetting the timeout - not sure what you’re trying to achieve. In the fiddle warntime is a global variable, can’t you just monitor the on click event in user input as well as the input value and reset the warntime?